# Chart.js Text color

Tags: javascript, chart.js

So im using chart.js
http://www.chartjs.org/docs/
and i cant change the color of the text in the bottom

ex:
"January","February","March","April","May","June","July"
and the numbers in the left side

i tried all these options:
                    scaleFontColor: "#FFFFFF"
                    pointLabelFontColor : "#FFFFFF"

my full code:

```
<script>
    var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};
    var lineChartData = {
        labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
        datasets : [
            {
                label: "My Second dataset",
                fillColor : "rgba(255, 89, 114, 0.6)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(51, 51, 51, 1)",
                pointColor : "rgba(255, 89, 114, 1)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                scaleFontColor: "#FFFFFF",
                pointLabelFontColor : "#FFFFFF",
                pointLabelFontSize : 30,
                data : [1,2,10,7,3,1]
            }
        ]

    }

window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
        responsive: true
    });
}


</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`scaleFontColor` is used to change the color of the labels.

Instead of putting it in your datasets you should add it as a parameter in your function, like this:

```
window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
    responsive: true, scaleFontColor: "#FFFFFF" }
});
```

Comment: interesting, but it doesnt seem to work unfortunately. its not doing anything

Comment: Does not work with Chart.js 2.1.3 using Line Chart with time scales.

Answer (score 32):

The working code is this:

```
Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontColor = "#fff";
```

Have fun :)

Comment: Is it  possible to set this "per chart"?

Comment: I expect there's a more correct way but I set it again before each chart is created which works.

Answer (score 12):

In Chart.js v3 it can be achieved with:

```
Chart.defaults.color = "#ff0000";
```

Comment: This is the option you'll have to go for when using 
react-chartjs-2

Answer (score 7):

For chart.js 3.x migration, text-labels on x and y axis are set this way:

Set options to the following:

```
scales: {
  x: {
    ticks: {
      color: "red"
    }
  },
  y: {
    ticks: {
      color: "green"
    }
  }
}
```

similar solution is found if you want to change color of grid lines, inside of x / y value write

```
grid: {
  color: "white"
}
```

Comment: do you know what the option is to change the colour of the text in the legend or where I can find the documentation?

Comment: documentation can be found at [3.x Migration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/getting-started/v3-migration.html) i think the legends if i understand you right can be changed by adding this to the `x` and `y` properties seen in my answer

`title: { display: true,  text: "Legend", color: "#FFF" },`

Comment: Man you killed it!

Answer (score 0):

i found the issue together with Kenan

```
<script>
    var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};
    var lineChartData = {
        labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
        datasets : [
            {
                label: "My Second dataset",
                fillColor : "rgba(255, 89, 114, 0.6)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(51, 51, 51, 1)",
                pointColor : "rgba(255, 89, 114, 1)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                data : [1,2,10,7,3,1]
            }
        ]

    }

    window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
        responsive: true, scaleFontColor: "#FFFFFF" }
)};
</script>
```

it wasnt a normal datatype and i had to adjust the brackets properly!

thanks alot,looks great now.