# Chart.js: Chaing Font Color and Size not working

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to change the font size and color of the labes on the Y- and X-Axis. The documentation says that you simply have to set the `scaleFontColor` and `scaleFontSize`:

```
    var config = {
        scaleFontColor: "#6E6E6E",
        scaleFontSize: 16,
        type: "line",
        data: {
            labels: labelsFromEntries(entriesAll),
            datasets: []
        },

        options: {
            responsive: true,
            title: {
                display: false
            },
            legend: {
                position: "bottom"
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    type: "time",
                    time: {
                        unit: "hour",
                        format: "HH:mm",
                        tooltipFormat: "HH:mm",
                        displayFormats: {
                            hour: "HH:mm",
                            day: "HH:mm",
                            week: "HH:mm",
                            month: "HH:mm",
                            quarter: "HH:mm",
                            year: "HH:mm"
                        }
                    },
                    gridLines : {
                        display : false
                    }
                }, ],
                yAxes: [{}]
            },
        }
```

This has no effect at all with Version: 2.1.3!

So how can you really change the font color and size of Y- and X-Axis labels?

Comment: See if this helps:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546677/chart-js-text-color

Comment: That is exactly what i have. And as i said it is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You misunderstood how Chart.js is working (*which I can understand since it is a real mess to edit it*).

What you want to edit is the tick labels of your axes, and not their title.
Then, you must know that the `fontSize` and `fontColor` attributes you are looking for are stored in `scales.xAxes.ticks`.

So you just have to edit them like this :

```
var options = {
    // ...
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                fontSize: 30,
                fontColor: "red"
            }
        }]
    }
    // ...
}
```

And then add this `var` to your chart options.

---

Here is a fully working example of you what you want :

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# of Votes',
            data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    // Edit here for the yAxe
                    beginAtZero:true,
                    fontColor: "red",
                    fontSize: 30
                }
            }],
            xAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    // Edit here for the xAxe
                    fontColor: "#456ef4",
                    fontSize: 20
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.6/Chart.min.js"></script>
  
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the latest doc: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/.

The font size can be set by changing `scaleLabel` object

```
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: "time",
                gridLines : {
                    display : false
                },
                scaleLabel : { fontColor: '#6E6E6E', fontSize:16 }
            }],
        },
```

Comment: Nothing changing at all when i add scaleLabel properties.

Comment: Maybe you missunderstood what i want to do. I dont want to change the titles of the Y- and X-Axis. I dont even show them. I want to change the LABELS. of the Y- AndX-Axis.