# changing text color within jquery pie chart

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

hi everyone im in the process of building a simple bootstrap website and ive installed a jquery pie chart script.. however im not at all sure how to change the text color within the chart.. here is the code and an a link to webpage to show whats going on.. pie chart can be found in $CARROT section at bottom ..thanks so much for any help https://www.begrudgedbunnies.com/

```
<script>
              jQuery(document).ready(function () {
                var chartDiv = $("#barChart");
                var myChart = new Chart(chartDiv, {
                  type: 'pie',
                  data: {
                    labels: ["Airdrops & Staking", "Liquidity", "Begrudged DAO", "Dev Team", "Promo"],
                    datasets: [
                      {
                        data: [60000000, 15000000, 10000000, 10000000, 5000000],
                        backgroundColor: [
                          "#FF6384",
                          "#4BC0C0",
                          "#FFCE56",
                          "#E7E9ED",
                          "#36A2EB"
                        ]
                      }]
                  },
                  options: {
                    title: {
                      display: true,
                      text: 'Total Supply 100,000,000'
                    },
                    responsive: true,
                    maintainAspectRatio: true,
                  }
                });
              });
            </script>
```

Comment: [Here's some answers on how to change the font color in chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546677/chart-js-text-color)